# Как оставить сокет не тронутым при перевороте экрана?

Tags: java, android, сокет, tcp, android-bundle

Как сделать чтобы `Socket` не отсоединялся от сервера при повороте экрана, ну точнее не становился `null`'ом? В принципе можно было бы сохранить его сохранить с помощью `Bundle`, но там сохранение всех типов происходит почему-то в тип `String` ...

```
    private static final String autherised=null;

 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(autherised,true);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Поэтому мне кажется что с сложным объектом (Сокетом) такой трюк не пройдёт. Так куда мне лучше сохранить `Socket` или где его создать чтоб его `activity` своими перезагрузками не трогало?

Answer (score 3):

Вынеси весь свой сетевой код в отдельный [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) и перезагрузка `Activity` его не коснется.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, а как мне потом сокет из сервиса в переменную заганять, при перезапуске активити (перевороте экрана)?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy http://stackoverflow.com/a/9959520/5634351

Comment: Сокет не надо передавать в активити. Передавайте только сами данные.

Comment: А как мне передать в сервис callback "public interface"? Ну или для примера хотя-бы класс какой нибудь и что-бы можно было из активити в сервисе получить содержимое какой нибудь переменной, а там дальше я сам доделаю.

Comment: например так http://stackoverflow.com/q/14985678